# Как исправить скачки при наведении

Tags: html, css, hover, border

```css
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr {
    transition: 0.1s all;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr:hover {
    border: 5px solid #9C9C9C;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-right: none;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3-rigt {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__p {
    margin-top: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__price {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__buy {
    background: #669933;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 50px  18px 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 17px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
}
```

```html
   
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант сделать цвет `border` изначально прозрачным, а по `hover` менять цвет.

```css
.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: none;
  transition: 0.1s all;
  text-align: center;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr:hover {
  border-color: #9C9C9C;
  height: 320px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3-rigt {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__p {
  margin-top: 17px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__price {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__buy {
  background: #669933;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 50px 18px 50px;
  position: relative;
  //left: 40px;
  //top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 17px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr">
  <h3 class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3"><span class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__h3-rigt">ჩვენი</span><br>ახალი კომპლექტი!</h3>
  <p class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__p">ორი ერთადგილიანი სავარძელი</p>
  <p class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__p">ორი ტახტი</p>
  <p class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__p">მაგიდა</p>
  <p class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__price">მხოლოდ 950 ლარად!</p>
  <a href="#" class="Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr__buy">ყიდვა</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот парочка вариантов:

1. Если заменить эти правила

   ```
   .Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr {
       transition: 0.1s all;
       height: 340px;
    }
   .Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr:hover {
       border: 5px solid #9C9C9C;
       border-radius: 5px;
   }
   ```
2. Или еще вариант

   ```
   .Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr {
       padding: 5px 0;
       position: relative;
       border-radius: 5px;
       height: 320px;
    }
    .Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr:before {
       transition: 0.2s all;
       height: 100%;
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       width: calc(100% - 10px);
    }

    .Left-Content__Complect-Line__product__descr:hover:before {
       border: 5px solid #9C9C9C;
       border-radius: 5px;
    }
   ```